# Python truth table generator library

Tags: python

Hi I am using the following library to generate truth tables in python https://github.com/chicolucio/truth-table-generator. I can gnerate the tables fine using `NgC = ttg.Truths(['A', 'B'], ['A xor B'])` this gives me a table with all of the inputs and the outputs as shown below:

```
+-----+-----+-----------+
|  A  |  B  |  A xor B  |
|-----+-----+-----------|
|  1  |  1  |     0     |
|  1  |  0  |     1     |
|  0  |  1  |     1     |
|  0  |  0  |     0     |
+-----+-----+-----------+
```

Now what i want to do is get the data from the table which is created I can get the attributes of the NgC object using `pprint(vars(NgC))`

this gives me the following attributes:

```
{'base_conditions': [(True, True),
                     (True, False),
                     (False, True),
                     (False, False)],
 'bases': ['A', 'B'],
 'ints': True,
 'p': re.compile('(?<!\\w)(A|B)(?!\\w)'),
 'parens': nested () expression,
 'phrases': ['A xor B'],
 'to_match': {W:(ABCD...) | "A" | "B" | "not" | "-" | "~" | "or" | "nor" | "xor" | "and" | "nand" | "=>" | "implies" | "=" | "!="}}
```

I can then get the input data from the table using `NcG.base_conditions` but I am unsure how to get the results column from the NcG object thats to say I dont know how to get the result A xor B from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want something like this?

```
ngC.as_pandas()['A xor B']
```

---

```
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0
Name: A xor B, dtype: object
```

Comment: From what I can see that kinda works but im not sure how i would acces the individual bits. Lets say I want to now assign the value 1 from row 3 to a new variable?

Comment: Actually i mean if I use the code which you suggest `ngC.as_pandas()['A xor B']` how would I set a new variable call it A = 1 where the value 1 assigned to A comes from the 3rd row of the table. I am new to programming python so maybe its really simple and im missing something.

Comment: `ngC.as_pandas()['A xor B'][3]` <-------------------- 3rd index row

Comment: If you ever have to check what are the attributes or function is related to any variable just do `dir(<varname>)` and see the list of function/attribute you can apply. Close the question.